# Error when sending the request curl php in sendinblue

Tags: php, validation, curl, xampp, http-status-code-404

The XXXXXX are the key generated by sendinblue when you are registered and generate the key of api-key

```
$curl  =  curl_init ();

$headers[]  = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[]  = 'api-key: XXXXXX';

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

  CURLOPT_HEADER => 0, //TRUE para incluir el header en el output
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/emailCampaigns",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"recipients\":{\"listIds\":[\"2\"]},\"tag\":\"Ninguna\",\"sender\":{\"name\":\"{'name':'xyz' , 'email':'jrodriguez@cidesa.com.ve'}\",\"email\":\"jrodriguez@cidesa.com.ve\"},\"name\":\"JonathanG\",\"htmlContent\":\"La demostración usa derivadas\",\"subject\":\"Mi tema\",\"replyTo\":\"jonathangrodriguezt@gmail.com\",\"footer\":\"mi pie\",\"header\":\"mi cabeza\"}",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo "<pre>";
  echo print_r(json_decode($response,true));
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

As you will see the cogigo when executing this error

```
[code] => document_not_found
[message] => One or more list ids are not valid. Please enter valid list ids
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong annex image and address (https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#createemailcampaign-1) 
What I'm looking for is to create a campaign message to be sent in the code replaced the list that will be marked in blue in the image where is the parameters to generate the code put both the id of the contact, the id of the list, and the mail of the contact but none helped me. (2nd image Contact data)

**First image**

[image]

**Second image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$data = array(
     "name" => $title,
     "sender" => new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\CreateEmailCampaignSender(array('name'=>$from, 'email'=>$replay)), 
     "templateId" => $template_id, 
     "scheduledAt" => date('c', strtotime('2019-05-22 10:00:00')),
     "subject" => $subject,
     "replyTo" => $replay,
     "recipients"=> array("listIds"=> array(intval($list_id))),
     "inlineImageActivation" => true
);
```

Use to test, first the list id as number, and then try using `intval($list_id)`.